# Mongoose: "Possibly unhandled rejection". ContactList.insert is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Doing a small project using MEAN stack. And have a problem, when sending a post request, console.log shows an error.

[image: error]

**Error states:**

*Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"TypeError: ContactList.insert is not a function*

**My code for server side is following:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var logger = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/contactlist");

var ContactList = require("./server/models/contactList.js");


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'50mb', extended:true})); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{maxAge:1}));

app.get('/contactlist', function(req, res) {
  console.log('I received a get request');
  ContactList.find().exec(function(err, contacts) {
   //console.log(contacts);
   res.status(200).send(contacts);
 });
});

app.post('/contactlist', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  ContactList.insert(req.body, function(err, contacts) {
    res.json(contacts);
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
     console.log(`Express server running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
```

**I am not sure about the following code:**

```
app.post('/contactlist', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      ContactList.insert(req.body, function(err, contacts) {
        res.json(contacts);
      });
    });
```

**Controller code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response){
        console.log("I got the data I requested"); 
        $scope.contactList = response.data;
    });

    $scope.addContact = function() {
        console.log($scope.contact);
        $http.post('/contactlist', $scope.contact).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: The angular code is irrelevant here. The code you need to show is in `./server/models/contactList.js` where you probably are not exporting the model correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose models don't have an `.insert` method, they have [`.create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create):

```
ContactList.create(req.body, function(err, contacts) {
  res.json(contacts);
});
```

Make sure that you also add proper error handling.